# Load divs from td inside a container div, one at a time?

Tags: jquery

I checked out similar questions but couldn't find the answer.

I have this HTML:

```
<table>
<td>
<a href="#">click me</a>
<div class="showme"><p>test</p></div>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#">click me</a>
<div class="showme"><p>test 2</p></div>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#">click me</a>
<div class="showme"><p>test 3</p></div>
</td>
</table>

<div class="container" rel="showme"></div>
```

What I want: I want the div.showme to be hidden originally, and when the link inside the TD is clicked, that div.showme loads in div.container.

What I tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("td a").click(function() {  
        $(".showme").html($(this).attr('rel'));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will do what you want

```
$(function(){
        $("table td>a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //get the html content
            var cont = $(this).parent().children(".showme").html();
            //add it to the desired div
            $(".container").html(cont);
        });
    });
```

and you will need a little bit of css

```
.showme{
display: none;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

set your css to hide the "showme" initially

```
.showme { display:none}
```

And change your schipt to this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("td a").click(function() {  
        $(this).next().load($(this).attr('href'));
    });

});
```

Remember that you cannot open external links with javascript, if this is what you are trying to do then you might want to use an iframe instead of a div

Comment: wait, i misunderstood your question. i will edit post in a second

Comment: Yea, it is supposed to load in the container div

Answer (score 0):

add one div in your html

```
<table>
    <td>
        <a href="#">click me</a>
        <div class="showme">
            <p>
                test</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">click me</a>
        <div class="showme">
            <p>
                test 2</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">click me</a>
        <div class="showme">
            <p>
                test 3</p>
        </div>
    </td>
</table>
<div class="container"></div>
```

and script like this

```
 <style>
.showme { display:none}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("td").click(function () {
            var tow = $(this);
            tow.find('div[class="showme"]').css('display', 'block');
            $('.container').html(tow.find('div[class="showme"]'));
        });
    });
</script>
```